# How to reconcile the Terraform State with an existing bucket?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

Using Terraform 11.14
My terraform file contains the following resource:

```
resource "google_storage_bucket" "assets-bucket" {
  name          = "${local.assets_bucket_name}"
  storage_class = "MULTI_REGIONAL"
  force_destroy = true
}
```

And this bucket has already been created (it exists on the infrastructure based on a previous `apply`)
However the state (remote on `gcs`) is inconsistent and doesn't seem to include this bucket.
As a result, `terraform apply` fails with the following error:

```
google_storage_bucket.assets-bucket: googleapi: Error 409: You already own this bucket. Please select another name., conflict
```

How can I reconcile the state? (`terraform refresh` doesn't help)

**EDIT**

Following @ydaetskcoR's response, I did:

```
terraform import module.bf-nathan.google_storage_bucket.assets-bucket my-bucket
```

The output:

```
module.bf-nathan.google_storage_bucket.assets-bucket: Importing from ID "my-bucket"...
module.bf-nathan.google_storage_bucket.assets-bucket: Import complete! Imported google_storage_bucket (ID: next-assets-bf-nathan-botfront-cloud)
module.bf-nathan.google_storage_bucket.assets-bucket: Refreshing state... (ID: next-assets-bf-nathan-botfront-cloud)

Error: module.bf-nathan.provider.kubernetes: 1:11: unknown variable accessed: var.cluster_ip in:

https://${var.cluster_ip}
```

The refreshing step doesn't work. I ran the command from the project's root where a `terraform.tfvars` file exists.
I tried adding `-var-file=terraform.tfvars` but no luck. Any idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to import it into the existing state file. You can do this with the [`terraform import` command](https://www.terraform.io/docs/import/index.html) for any resource that supports it.

Thankfully the [`google_storage_bucket` resource does support it](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/storage_bucket.html#import):

> Storage buckets can be imported using the name or project/name. If the project is not passed to the import command it will be inferred from the provider block or environment variables. If it cannot be inferred it will be queried from the Compute API (this will fail if the API is not enabled).
>
> e.g.
>
> ```
> $ terraform import google_storage_bucket.image-store image-store-bucket
> $ terraform import google_storage_bucket.image-store tf-test-project/image-store-bucket
> ```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It only worked half way (see my edit). Do you have an idea what's causing this?

Comment: That's a completely different issue that requires a separate question that should also include your code that reproduces that error.

Comment: faire enough: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59885641/importing-a-google-storage-bucket-resource-in-terraform-state-fails