# Importing a google_storage_bucket resource in Terraform state fails

Tags: google-cloud-storage, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I'm trying to import a `google_storage_bucket` storage bucket in my Terraform state:

```
terraform import module.bf-nathan.google_storage_bucket.assets-bucket my-bucket
```

However, it fails as follows:

```
module.bf-nathan.google_storage_bucket.assets-bucket: Importing from ID "my-bucket"...
module.bf-nathan.google_storage_bucket.assets-bucket: Import complete! Imported google_storage_bucket (ID: next-assets-bf-nathan-botfront-cloud)
module.bf-nathan.google_storage_bucket.assets-bucket: Refreshing state... (ID: next-assets-bf-nathan-botfront-cloud)

Error: module.bf-nathan.provider.kubernetes: 1:11: unknown variable accessed: var.cluster_ip in:

https://${var.cluster_ip}
```

The refreshing step doesn't work. I ran the command from the project's root where a `terraform.tfvars` file exists.

I tried adding `-var-file=terraform.tfvars` but no luck.

Note that the variables are correctly interpolated with all other terraform commands.

It's worth noting that the bucket in question is defined in a module and not in the `main.tf`. Here is how the bucket is declared:

````
resource "google_storage_bucket" "assets-bucket" {
  name          = "${local.assets_bucket_name}"
  storage_class = "MULTI_REGIONAL"
  force_destroy = true
}
```
````

Comment: This sounds like you are running into https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/13018. Can you confirm?

Comment: aha! So the only way to fix that is to substitute variable with actual values in the module then?

Comment: At least for the provider, it seems so.